# No matching provisioning profiles found for Applications/ ***.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, app-store, provisioning-profile

I get this error when I am trying to validate the build before submitting it to the AppStore. I tried all possible solutions like -

1. Deleting profiles and recreating it.
2. I even tried creating a new APP ID.
3. Created a new Project and copied all the files and folders.

What exactly are these errors? Why is it occurring? How to resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ex. App Name : appname
App bundle identifier com.xyz.appname

1. Create AppId 
   Ex. bundelID : com.xyz.appname AppID Name: AppName
2. Create Provisioning Profile and select AppID : AppName
   Select Device you want to add in Provisioning Profile
3. in provisioning profile check bind current AppID according your App

Add your Device UDID in Provisioning Profile in iTune Connect
also Ap